# MinGW Makefile is looking in c:\windows\system32 instead of /usr/bin

Tags: windows, makefile, path, mingw, gnu-make

The following Makefile:

```
.PHONY: all

all: $(shell find example/data)
    @echo $(shell which find)
```

When run with gnuwin32 Make in a MinGW bash shell, outputs the following:

```
$ make
FIND: Parameter format not correct
/usr/bin/find
```

This output is strange because the "FIND: Parameter format not correct" message comes from Windows' *find.exe* in *C:\Windows\system32*.

This means that:

- `$(shell find example/data)` is using *C:\Windows\system32\find.exe*, even though
- `$(shell which find)` identifies */usr/bin/find* (the GNU find)

My question is: What is going on here? Why would `$(shell find ...)` be looking in *C:\Windows\system32* instead of in */usr/bin*? Why isn't the path consistent and what can I do to make `$(shell find ...)` behave the same way that `find ...` would behave from the MinGW bash shell?

I do not want to hard code the path to `find`; and I could probably get what I want by using `which` to find the path but I'm more concerned with the path being incorrect than I am about specifically getting `find` to work here.

Comment: Most likely because `which` is a UNIX program, and so it looks at UNIX paths first or something like that.  I don't do windows and I can't keep straight all the different environments and how they interact.  Just to remind, GNU make doesn't care which shell _started_ it, it always uses the value of the `SHELL` make variable and if that's not set, it will find a shell on its own.

Comment: @MadScientist Even if I force `SHELL` to cmd or /bin/sh or /usr/bin/bash, it doesn't change the behavior, strangely.

Comment: I can't remember if the GNU make `shell` function uses the value of `SHELL`.  It might be that it's hardcoded to use the "internally discovered" shell.  If you run the command directly in the recipe instead of using `$(shell ...)` (obviously this won't work for the prerequisites) do you see different behavior?  Anyway, sorry but as above I just don't know much about these crazy Windows environments and how they interact.  You can try using `make -d` and maybe it will print something helpful.  Or not.

Answer (score 0):

When you say "MinGW bash shell" I assume you mean an MSYS/MSYS2 bash shell.

MSYS and MSYS2 provide a Unix/Linux-like shell, and some commands may exist in Unix/Linux with the same name as different commands in Windows.

The `find` is such a command.

There are several solutions to your problem:

- Use the `where` command instead (your `Makefile` will be compatible with other platforms).
- Specify the full path to the command you want to use. You could detect it with `FINDCMD=$(shell which find)` and then run it with `$(shell $(FINDCMD) example/data)`